# Impromptu TCP sender/receiver

Tags: c, socket

Every once in a while I need to get some random computer thing done; so I write something to do it for me. This is one of those. It needed to be able to send text to, and receive text from, a server - without blocking. I am asking for feedback with the premise of what kind of code this is: A one-use hack.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define BUFLEN 1024

volatile static int run = 1;

void sendx(int sd) {
    int sent, i;
    char buffer[BUFLEN], ch;
    do {
        i = 0;
        do {
            ch = getc(stdin);
            buffer[i] = ch;
            i++;
        } while (ch != '\n' && i < BUFLEN);
        sent = write(sd, buffer, i);
    } while (sent == i && run);
}

void recvx(int sd) {
    char nothing[] = { '?' };
    int len, i;
    char buffer[BUFLEN];
    do {
        len = read(sd, buffer, BUFLEN);
        i = 0;
        while (i < len) {
            if (isprint(buffer[i]))
                write(1, buffer + i, 1);
            else write(1, nothing, 1);
            i++;
        }
    } while (len > 0 && run);
    close(sd);
    nothing[0] = '\n';
    write(0, nothing, 1);
    fflush(stdin);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int sd, pid;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

    assert(argc == 3);
    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    assert(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &addr.sin_addr) > 0);
    addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
    assert(sd > -1);
    assert(connect(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) > -1);
    pid = fork();
    assert(pid > -1);
    if (pid == 0)   sendx(sd);
    else        recvx(sd);
    run = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the logic is nicely encapsulated in functions sendx and recvx, but then main disappoints with its lump of code. It would be better to leave main in charge of parsing and validating the command line arguments, and extract the rest to functions with descriptive names.

In main the `assert(argc == 3)` should come before the first memset: no need to initialize memory if you might not use it.

In sendx, the variable i is used for two purposes: loop variable for reading input, and input size. If you extract the input reading to a function that returns the number of characters read, then in sendx you can store that in a variable with a descriptive name, and the logic of the main responsibility of this method will become clearer.

Answer (score 3):

### Run variable

It seems like you want to use the `run` variable to cause one process to stop if the other one stops.  But since each process has its own copy of the `run` variable, it currently remains at value 1 and serves no purpose.

There are several ways to achieve interprocess communication if you really need this feature (e.g. shared memory, pipes, `kill()`, `waitpid()`, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Code does not distinguish between EOF and some `char`.

`getc(stdin)` returns ant `int` in the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  This typically 257 difference values cannot be stored uniquely in a `char`.

```
// char ch;
int ch;
...
  ch = getc(stdin);
  // add
  if (ch == EOF) break;
...
} while (ch != '\n' && i < BUFLEN);
```

---

`fflush(stdin);`, although defined on some systems in undefined behavior as `stdin` is not an output stream nor an update stream .

> If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream ...  the fflush function causes any unwritten data ... to be delivered ...; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
>   "7.21.5.2 The fflush function"

---

I would expect the test of `run` to occur at the beginning of the loop.  (2 places)

---

Niche concern: `is...()` functions are defined only for values of the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  Current code may fail on reading data with the value of 255 (Some encodings: `'ÿ'`), which would likely save in a `char` as a -1.  `isprint(-1)` is likely false as `isprint()` may see that as `print(EOF)`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25382347/2410359

```
char buffer[BUFLEN];  // or use unsigned char buffer[BUFLEN]
if (isprint((unsigned char) buffer[i]))
```

---

Minimize use of magic numbers:

```
// write(1, nothing, 1);
write(1, nothing, sizeof nothing);
```

---

<strike>`recvx()` and `sendx()` both use `sd` asynchronously to each other.  When `recvx(int sd)` closes `sd`, `sendx()` may not know that and need to.  Suggest passing the address of `sd` so both routines access the same index which should be set to a invalid index after `recvx(int sd)` closes it.  This volatile value could then be tested as `sendx()` needs it.</strike> per @JS comment.

Comment: What you said about setting `sd` to an invalid index won't work because `recvx()` and `sendx()` are being run in two different processes.

Comment: @JS Agreed about `sd`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `assert` for error checking! Those statements will be removed when the code is compiled with optimisation turned on. `assert` is meant as a "sanity check" for the programmer - use it to test for coding error, not errors in environment or user. In it's current state, this program would crash if the user forgets an argument if optimisation is turned on. `assert` is controlled by the macro `NDEBUG`.

I recommend switching to using `exit`, and preferably a message describing the error. Don't leave the user guessing. `perror` is convient for when system calls and standard function fail.